# How to combine two node/add/* forms into one form but create two different types of content in drupal 7 on submitting it?

Tags: forms

I want to combine two content/add/* forms into one form but create two different types of content in drupal 7 on submittiing a single from.

Comment: I have two content types. One is Job Apply form and other is questionnaire. User can create any number of questionnaire. While creating a job I want user to select a questionnaire from dropdown of existing questionaires. That questionnaire will get attached to the job apply form. But I am getting two different forms, but I want one submit button.

Comment: Have you checked this thread : http://drupal.org/node/334817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thought on a solution was also entity reference and entity inline form but a few caveats regarding the latter. The enitity inline form adds a submit for the additional content type, this seems against your proposed UX so you will need a hook_form_alter to change this behaviour (and indeed the label)  have a look at http://drupal.org/node/1880850 for a solution I worked on that will give you a lead in (but not a solution to) this.

The other issue is that I got a lot of annoying but non-fatal and non-damaging errors when I loaded entity inline form so stability may not be 100% there. This could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module by which,

- you can reference one node from another node, hence creating a relationship between the two.

> - add a node reference field in your **Job** content type which will reference **Questionnaire** content type.
> - you should have some **questionnaire** nodes first
> - when you create a **job**, you should get a list of **questionnaires** to chose from
> - in 'Manage Display' for the **Job** content type, chose **Rendered node** as display for the node reference field - So in node view of the job you will have the questionnare node displayed too.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Inline Entity Form](http://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) and [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference).

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification,
>   removal) of referenced entities.

Set up your *Job Apply* content type and add an *Entity Reference* field with an Inline Entity Form Widget to reference your *Questionnaire* entities.

This means that on the add/edit pages your users will have the ability to either create a new *Questionnaire* or reference an existing one.